# Error making a selection in Teradata with R

Tags: sql, r, teradata

When I try to import teradata data with a where in the sql statement I get the following error

```r
clients<-dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from clients where year(cl_dataentrada) = 2018")
```

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: expected something between the 'where' keyword and the 'year' keyword.

```r
clients<-data.frame(clients)
```

I've also tried:

```r
clients<- dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT * from clients where year(cl_dataentrada) = 2018")
```

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: expected something between the 'where' keyword and the 'year' keyword.

Also in a sql chunk :

```
SELECT * from clients where year(cl_dataentrada) = 2018
```

Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1344: 42000: [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseSyntax error: expected something between the 'where' keyword and the 'year' keyword. 
Failed to execute SQL chunk

Comment: This could be a driver issue. Can you please try with `Extract(year from cl_dataentrada)`. the function `year` is an odbc function not Teradata - so may be that is one of the reasons that is causing error

Answer (score 0):

As Shiva Prakash suggested this finally works:

clients<-dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from clients where extract(year from cl_dataentrada)=2018")

It was an error because the function year is an odbc function not Teradata. 
Thank you.